# binding a button wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I need a name of button to bind it, for example: `buttonname.Bind` etc. But in my code I don't have any names of buttons, only ID's, because I work with `AddMany`.

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)

vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


gbox = wx.GridSizer(8, 2, 8, 8)
gbox.AddMany([(wx.StaticText(panel, label="test"), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel, label = a), wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.TextCtrl(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel, label = result), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel, label="test"), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel), wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.TextCtrl(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel, label="test"), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel), wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.TextCtrl(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel, label="test"), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.StaticText(panel), wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.TextCtrl(panel), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND),
              (wx.Button(panel, label = "rtfhd"), wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND)
              ]
              )
vbox.Add(gbox, proportion = 1,  flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border = 20)

panel.SetSizer(vbox)
```

Comment: The button can be declared as a separate named widget and then included in the AddMany. The AddMany function of a Sizer, is arguably much abused and in my view, at least, best avoided.

Comment: You could retrieve the added elements with gbox.GetChildren(), but as Rolf wrote, better create and add one by one and keep references where needed.
E.g. how would you retrieve the contents of the TextCtrls once finished?

Answer (score 0):

every window can be given a name='name' and by using 'FindWindowByName' the window can be determined for the Bind